# How to add class on mat-menu overlay in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I checked mat-menu API (https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api#MatMenu) but I couldn't find how to add a class on mat-menu cdk overlay.

I want to add a class on cdk overlay which contains mat-menu template. Can anyone help on the same?

I want to add class on parent cdk overlay because in responsive menu is not opening correctly. Check this below image.

[image]

Comment: You can add a class to your <mat-menu> element - is that not working?  What exactly are you trying to do? Can you create a stackblitz example?

Comment: Actually, I want to apply a class on parent cdk overlay because in responsive it is not showing perfectly.

Comment: I can see the problem, but without code I can't know why it occurs. Plus I don't know what you plan to do to fix it. You can't add a class to a dynamically injected element, but you can override classes globally. Have you tried `<mat-menu class="my-class">`? Classes set that way are dynamically applied to the .mat-menu-panel div that is the child of the .cdk-overlay-pane div. See 'panelClass' under the [MatMenu API docs](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api#MatMenu).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add `backdropClass` to the `mat-menu`, and then add style in the global style file. That `cdk-overlay-pane` is the one you want to style for, I think. For example:

```
<mat-menu #subMenu="matMenu" backdropClass="sg-vertical-sub-menu">
</mat-menu>

.sg-vertical-sub-menu+* .cdk-overlay-pane {
    margin-top: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Some deep-digging in the docs is required to find this.

Comment: missing something on the element + element Selector.  I am not able to get this to work.  ```.sg-vertical-sub-menu+* .cdk-overlay-pane```

Comment: This add class to cdk-overlay-backdrop but i need to add it on one level above that is cdk-overlay-container

Comment: This won't work if hasBackdrop is set to false. Any ideas for that case?

Answer (score 5):

@Tom Jiang did it works fine, but adding css in styles.css might be a bit inconvenient and difficult to find code.

**The better way:** If you want to change your component only without affecting other components, you should add a class to the menu.

```
<mat-menu #infoMenu="matMenu" class="customize"></mat-menu>
```

Then style your menu with ::ng-deep.

```
::ng-deep .customize {
  background: red;
}
```

voila!! your customization will not affect other components.

Comment: cdk-overlay is not included in mat-menu element, it's inserted in body, so your solution is not correct.

Comment: Also, we shouldn't use `::ng-deep` anymore, since it's deprecated

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, this is what I've done to position the menu below my toolbar.

```html
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane {
  top: 48px!important;
}
```

Comment: The response is great but it affects all ckd-overlay-pane. Adding a backdropClass is preferable

Comment: Also heads up that `::ng-deep` is going deprecated.